# string datetime format to time() unix time format in python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I know this must be a well covered question elsewhere, but most questions I saw on SO looked like they were going in the opposite direction.  I understand how to convert FROM `time.time()` TO human-readable datetime format as follows:

```
>>> import time, datetime
>>> thetime = time.time()
>>> thetime
1375289544.41976
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(thetime).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2013-07-31 12:51:08'
```

What's the function for going the inverse direction?

```
>>> thetime = '2013-07-30 21:23:14.744643'
>>> time.strptime(thetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 454, in _strptime_time
    return _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: .744643
```

I'd like to go from the string to the seconds since the epoch format.

**UPDATE**

This is what I'm using, but it seems inelegant---there must be a function that does this already, right?

```
def datetostamp(x):
    thetime = x.split('.')
    return(time.mktime(time.strptime(thetime[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) + float('.'+thetime[1]))

>>> thetime = '2013-07-30 21:23:14.744643'
>>> datetostamp(thetime)
1375233794.744643
```

**UPDATE 2**

Maybe more simply, I'm just missing the format code for fractions of seconds?

Comment: Which Python version are you on?

Comment: Looks like version 2.7.3

Comment: There is an easier method for Py3x. You do still lose some of the precision though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **were** missing the format for fractions of a second.

`time.strptime(thetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")`

Comment: Cool, I thought so, but that still seems to drop beyond 1 decimal place.

Comment: interestingly `datetime.strptime(thetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")` doesn't